# How can I configure vagrant to use the same forwarded port for different nodes on different ips?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

I would like 10.211.11.100:8080 to forward to port 4369 on the machine with ip 10.211.11.100.

I would like 10.211.11.101:8080 to forward to port 4369 on the machine with ip 10.211.11.101.

If I try something like this:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 4369, host: 4369, host_ip: 10.211.11.100
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 4369, host: 4369, host_ip: 10.211.11.101
```

I get an error message like this:

```
Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
would collide with some other application that is already listening
on these ports. The forwarded port to 4369 is already in use
on the host machine.
```

There must be a way to specify the same port number at different IPs.  I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

which vagrant version are you using ?

normally [Support for port forwarding in an IP aliased environment](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4608) issue has been fixed since vagrant 1.9.2

Comment: vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.9.5

Comment: Although, thank you for referencing that. I found this:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8423#issuecomment-296209638

Apparently I need to downgrade? Trying that now...